# Magento2.4: Checkout Page loading issue

Tags: checkout, jquery, magento2.4

when I login into the checkout page after login checkout page not loading only loader loads.
in console Getting this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[href=#shipping]
```

Comment: Do you get this issue with guest checkout or only on login? sounds like on of your modules are conflicting or your theme could potentially not compatible with the version of magento

Comment: only while login on checkout  page (Guest and already logging working fine)

Comment: id suggest disabling all your modules which affect the checkout and enabling them one by one

Comment: Thanks, @DavaGordon it module's jquery issue.

Comment: glad to hear. now its just a matter of debugging your issue to find the solution. if you require additional help please feel free to update the question

Comment: Thank you @DavaGordon. I will figure it out :)